# How to make an object follow the movements of an animated object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, transform, gameobject

So I've animated my spaceship. With it's previous rigid form I've got a particle system coming out of it's wings. Now that it's animated, I still want those particles to follow all of it's wings movements, but the particles don't move along with the animations, even being parented with the gameobject's wings, showcase video, 19seconds: https://youtu.be/XJNjT4s4X6I

How can I make those particles move along with it's wings movements? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to parent them with the bone of the armature, I don't remember if it worked for me though, but what I did is to add an empty in the modeling program to follow the animation and export it, so I can parent it to the things I needed, for you It would be the Particle System.

Comment: Hey, it worked as you said. But no need to create extra empty gameobjects, just dragged my particle system to the bone as a child of the bone and it worked perfectly. Thanks!